# "Swing-Shell" java.lang.InternalError: Could not initialize COM: HRESULT=0x80010106

Tags: windows-store, java-9, desktop-bridge

I have a Java 9 app that I'm trying to package for the Windows Store. The strange thing is that it works as expected when I run the exe-launcher directly, but I get the following strange error when I run the launcher via the APPX package:

```
Exception in thread "Swing-Shell" java.lang.InternalError: Could not 
initialize COM: HRESULT=0x80010106 
at java.desktop/sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolderManager2.initializeCom(Native Method) 
at java.desktop/sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolderManager2$ComInvoker$1.run(Unknown Source at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

`HRESULT=0x80010106` means `RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE` which I guess means that COM is somehow already initialized in MTA mode. But why is this only an issue in the Windows Bridge sandbox? Does the Windows Bridge somehow `pre-initialize` COM somehow for some reason?

I'm not sure if this is a Java 9 issue, or a Desktop Bridge issue, or both. Does anybody have any ideas on how to identify the cause of the issue or workaround?

I have made a minimal [Sample Project](https://github.com/rednoah/JDK-8189938) to reproduce the issue

The application works when executed directly, but not when executed via the APPX launcher. Why?

Comment: A possible thread dump would be a better insight and reporting this to open jdk mailing list, bug tracker etc should also help.

Comment: Not sure if these are related, but do take a look at [JDK-8189604](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8189604)

Comment: Can you distill this down to a small test case that reproduces the issue so that it can be attached to https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8189938 .

Comment: I have added a test case:
https://github.com/rednoah/JDK-8189938

@AlanBateman Since I don't have an OpenJDK account, maybe you can help me update the bug report with the example application?

Comment: @AlanBateman The issue does not duplicate outside of the APPX container. Running `jar -jar main.jar` works as expected with Java 9.

Comment: `JDK-8189938` as been marked as resolved, without actually being resolved, or looking / running my example project. Not cool.

Comment: @rednoah Did you try accessing the same on [JDK10](http://jdk.java.net/10/)? The issue is marked resolve on the version 10.

Comment: Same issue with `jdk-10-ea+32`. The bug reviewer didn't have the Windows SDK installed and thus couldn't build an APPX package to reproduce the issue.

That particular piece of native code where the exception is thrown didn't change between [Java 8](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/windows/native/sun/windows/ShellFolder2.cpp#l234) and [Java 9](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/file/65464a307408/src/java.desktop/windows/native/libawt/windows/ShellFolder2.cpp#l257).

Comment: If I had access to all the Java 9 EA builds than I could narrow down which build introduced the issue, but I can't find them for download anywhere and I couldn't figure out how to build them myself from source.

Comment: I'm using Java 9 at both compile time as well as runtime. The error message indicates that `ant` is using Java 8. You can set the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to make `ant` use your Java 9 install. You will also need to make sure that `makeappx` is in the `%PATH%`. That's part of the UWP SDK.

Comment: As suggest in bug please try with Java JDK9 b57 version

Comment: Where can I download the `JDK9 b57` release files?

Comment: I would ideally expect @AlanBateman to write up an answer over the plan for resolving this or where can these be tested if already resolved.

Comment: @AlanBateman I'm happy to test new or old JDK builds anytime. Just give me a download link. ;)

Comment: @rednoah JDK 8u151 should work: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/pt/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Comment: @karliwson Yes. Java 8 runs fine, but Swing doesn't correctly render on HiDPI screens, so I need Java 9 / JEP 263.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Analysis

The JDK parts, that rely on COM being initialized (D3DPipeline, Sound and windows shellfolder access) all follow the same pattern:

- the run the code in a separate thread
- for this thread `CoInitialize` is called
- at the end of the user level code `CoUnitialize` is called

This is in line with the documentation the MSDN holds for COM and the analysis is correct, the error indicates, that the COM subsystem is already initialized to be MTA threaded.

So I modified the java launcher (*jvm.dll*) and inserted
debugging statements into some of the native methods in *os_windows.cpp*.
I focused on the threading methods. What I found was this:

- `create_main_thread`, `create_os_thread`, `pd_start_thread` all 
  run with COM not yet initialized
- the native thread initializer (`thread_native_entry`) is already
  running with COM initialized

I looked more into in `_beginthreadex` and indeed I finally found a lead
on stackoverflow. That pointed me to the sourcecode of *threadex.c*,
which is part of the Visual Studio 2013 Express Installation.

There you find, that `_beginthreadex` does not directly start the
supplied thread function, but runs a library initializer
(`_threadstartex`) first. Part of this initializer reads:

```
_ptd->_initapartment = __crtIsPackagedApp();
if (_ptd->_initapartment)
{
    _ptd->_initapartment = _initMTAoncurrentthread();
}

_callthreadstartex();
```

`_crtIsPackagedApp` detects via a kernel function if the application is
run as a "PackagedApp" (i.e. AppX package) and if so, then the
`RoInitialize` function is called, which from my understanding acts like the big
brother of CoInitialize.

Long story short: If your application is build with Visual Studio 2013
and run as a packaged application, you get a broken environment.

It was confirmed, that the working versions of the Oracle JDK were build with VS2010 SP1 and the broken version was build with VS2013SP4.

## Workaround

With the above information google finally found a reference, that supports the analysis:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/07/07/using-visual-c-runtime-in-centennial-project/

Quote from that article:

> Note that the existing VC++ 12.0 libraries created during the
>   Windows 8 timeframe have runtime checks to determine whether the
>   app is running under the app container or not. When running
>   desktop apps as a packaged app, these checks might limit the
>   functionality of the desktop app or cause it to behave like a UWA
>   (Universal Windows Application) (limited file system access or
>   create thread initializing MTA etc.). We have fixed this behavior
>   in the VC++ libraries contained in these framework packages and
>   thus removing the modern app limitations from your desktop
>   applications.

So I see to options to fix applications, that shall be distributed as AppX packages:

- either force the users to have the updates VC++ 12.0 binaries installed (by introducing the dependency cited in the blog post) or
- replace the `msvcr120.dll` that is bundled with Java 9 (and I assume also Java 10) with the fixed version from the update packages

I would go with the second version and I tested this. Starting with a clean up-to-date Windows 10 System, I installed JDK 9.0.4, I cloned the supplied testcase, modified it use the locally installed JRE (not the JDK!) and build the appx package. Running this, I reproduced the problem. I then replaced the `msvcr120.dll`'s in the JRE folder of my systems installation with the one contained in the APPX container from:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53176

*Hint: *.appx are just ZIP files with additional signatures, so you can
just rename them and extract the contents.*

I rebuild the testcase and it is working as it should (no COM
initialization errors anymore).